# member of a c struct returning nil in lua

Tags: c, lua

I have a C code where I'm passing a C structure to Lua. The code is as follows:

```c
int get_member_info(lua_State* Ls) {
    struct member_info *inf = (struct member_info*)lua_touserdata(Ls, 1);
    const char* key = lua_tostring(Ls, 2);
    
    if (strcmp(key, "p_time") == 0) {
        lua_pushinteger(Ls, inf->p_time);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(key, "id") == 0) {
        lua_pushinteger(Ls, inf->id);
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
    
int get_state_info(lua_State* Ls) {
    struct start_state *ss = (struct start_state*)lua_touserdata(Ls, 1);
    const char* key = lua_tostring(Ls, 2);
    
    if (strcmp(key, "open_start") == 0) {
        lua_pushboolean(Ls, ss->open_start);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(key, "change_state_time") == 0) {
        lua_pushinteger(Ls, ss->change_state_time);
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
    
struct member_info {
    int p_time;
    int id;
    ...
}
    
struct start_state {
    bool open_start;
    int change_state_time;
    ...
}
    
struct member_data {
    struct member_info member;
    struct start_state state;
    int unique_id;
    ....
}
    
int get_member_data(lua_State *Ls) {
    struct member_data *md = (struct member_data*)lua_touserdata(Ls, 1);
    
    lua_newtable(Ls);
    
    lua_pushstring(Ls, "member");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(Ls, &md->member);
    lua_newtable(Ls);
    lua_pushstring(Ls, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(Ls, get_member_info);
    lua_settable(Ls, -3);
    lua_setmetatable(Ls, -2);
    lua_settable(Ls, -3);
    
    lua_pushstring(Ls, "state");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(Ls, &md->state);
    lua_newtable(Ls);
    lua_pushstring(Ls, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(Ls, get_state_info);
    lua_settable(Ls, -3);
    lua_setmetatable(Ls, -2);
    lua_settable(Ls, -3);
    
    lua_pushstring(Ls, "unique_id");
    lua_pushinteger(Ls, md->unique_id);
    lua_settable(Ls, -3);
    
    return 1;
}
```

And the Lua code is:

```
local data = GetData()
local mb = get_member_data(data)
print(mb.member, mb.member.p_time, mb.state, mb.state.change_state_time, mb.unique_id)
```

The problem is that when I try to print all members of the struct like so:

```
print(mb.member, mb.member.p_time, mb.state, mb.state.change_state_time, mb.unique_id)
```

`mb.member.p_time` returns nil because it executes the `get_state_info` function instead of `get_member_info`. However, if I print only

```
print(mb.member, mb.member.p_time)
```

It works well and returns the `mb.member.p_time`. I would like to know how I can fix this so I can print everything correctly?

**Remember that I want to keep the designer of**

`mb.member` returns a struct pointer from C code

`mb.member.p_time` returns the timer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to give different **light** userdata objects individual metatables, which isn't possible, so you're actually setting the metatable for **all** light userdata objects each time you try to set it for one of them. You'll need to convert your code to use either tables or **full** userdata instead if you want different ones to have different metatables.

Comment: Could you show me examples of how I can do these two ways you mentioned?

Comment: @Michael https://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html

Comment: I need the `mb.member` pointer to have the same address as the c code because I use it in other functions that use the struct

From what I noticed the use of lua_newuserdata will not allow this or am I mistaken?

Could you give me an example in my case how I could use it?